# What's the best way of working out the Average Visit Duration for a blog with a high bounce rate?

Tags: google-analytics

I currently have a blog which gets almost all of its views from Google. As a result of this, I have a very high bounce rate - people find the article they wanted to read, read it, then generally leave and do something else.

However, this means that my Average Visit Duration stats in Google Analytics are almost entirely useless, since they don't count the AVD of 'bounces'. So I ask: what's the best way of calculating AVD in this scenario? I've heard ideas like events every 30 seconds - or measuring the distance scrolled by each reader. But is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks, J

Answer (score 0):

Nothing gets sent went he user leaves, so if the user only visits one page, you are going to see a high bounce rate with no or very low duration score.

Sending an event every 15-30 seconds is a good way to get users counted. The event doesn't have to mean anything, but it will affect the bounce rate and visitor duration.

I usually put something like this on most of my sites (classic code version):

```
setInterval(function(){_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','page','read-update']);},15000);
```